# HandleUnknownAction in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

What's an equivalent of ASP.NET MVC 5

```
Controller.HandleUnknownAction()
```

in ASP.NET MVC 6 / ASP.NET 5?

Comment: Curious what scenario do you generally use this method for? I see that you can send back a response probably saying that an action was not found or something of that sort...but is there anything else you use it for...

Comment: Dynamically generated templates. Say I have /Templates/EmployeeDetails
what i will do is first check if there is a file Views/Templates/EmployeeDetails.cshtml. If not I will use GenericDetails.cshtml which inside will use reflection to build a proper html to edit the Employee.

Would rather avoid the need to create action method + dedicated .cshtml for each type I have as 90% of them will be just 1-to-1 map of properties to html inputs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no real equivalent.

Action Selection in MVC5/WebAPI2 was a three stage process:
 1. Run the routes
 2. Select a controller
 3. Select an action

In MVC6, step 2 is gone. Actions are selected directly using route values - you'll notice that `Controller.BeginExecute` is gone as well. Controllers are 'thin' now.

You can simulate this behavior if you want by using a route that goes directly to your action in question.

Define an action called `HandleUnknownAction` in your controller

`routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
routes.MapRoute("unknown_action", "{controller}/{*params}", defaults: new { action = "HandleUnknownAction"});`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to simply define the unknown action as a parameter of your route:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class FooController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet("{viewName}")]
    public IActionResult HandleUnknownAction(string viewName)
    {
        return View(viewName);

    }
}
```

Using this approach, the url `foo/bar` would return the View `bar.cshtml`, `foo/baz` would return `baz.cshtml` etc.

Comment: Great suggestion. I'm moving an entire application to asp.net core and useful to have a placeholder until the actions are completed. I simply use 'return Ok("Unimplemented') for now instead of creating the view stubs.